# Get related objects through FK of a FK in django (will a _set work?)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

If I had a model structure like this:

```
class Camp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    reg_start = models.DateTimeField()
    reg_end = models.DateTimeField()

class Course(models.Model):
    camp = models.ForeignKey(Camp, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

class ClassDetail(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seat_count = models.IntegerField()
    limit_registrations = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Registration(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    class_detail = models.ForeignKey(CourseDetail, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

If I had a user that had (potentially) multiple `Registrations`, is there a quick and easy way to get a list of the id's of those camps?

This is what I currently have (which is working but I'm trying to see if I can eliminate the list comprehension)

```
        registration_queryset = Registration.objects.filter(
            person__id=user_id
        )

        camps_to_exclude = [
            x.course_detail.course.camp.id for x in registration_queryset
        ]
        # camp_list is an already existing queryset of camps
        camp_list = camp_list.exclude(
            id__in=camps_to_exclude,
        )
```

Comment: Did you try this in a shell? Also if you install `django_extensions` and `ipython`, the `shell_plus` command is great for experimenting.

Comment: I had not tried it in the shell, but thank you for the heads up - I'll definitely be playing around with that later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option. As long as they are querysets, django will reduce them into a single query. You can always check the query with `print(queryset.query)`.

```
camp_list.exclude(
    id__in=registration_queryset.values_list('course_detail__course__camp__id', flat=True),
)
```

Or you can do:

```
camp_list.exclude(
    course_set__classdetail_set__registration_set__person_id=user_id
).distinct()
```

The distinct will be necessary since you're crossing a pair of reverse foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks for this - the first option worked great. However, I did try the second option which did not work - but the first one works as intended.